# React: How do I create a button that only appears in certain rows of a DataGrid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid

In this web-app, we have 3 different types of users: Participants, Volunteers and Staff. The Volunteers are the only users that we store their "availability" in schedules that staff can view by clicking a "View Volunteer Schedule" button next to their row in the DataGrid.

This is how the DataGrid looks:

[DataGrid Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbiNG.png)

On the far left, there are buttons that will open a new tab with the user's schedule information.

This is the function of that button in ManageUser.jsx:

```
  /**
     * View Volunteer Schedule
     * @param e
     */
    function viewVolunteerSchedule(e) {
        if (e.row.data.role !== "Volunteer") {
            alert("This user is not a volunteer.", "Error");
        } else {
            let volunteerEmail = e.row.data.email;
            window.open("/admin/view-volunteer-schedule?email=" + volunteerEmail)
        }
    }
```

what I want to figure out is, rather than having this button appear on every row, displaying an error message when it is clicked on a non-volunteer - how do I go about making this button only appear in rows where the condition is met: "this user is a volunteer"?

The `<DataGrid>` in the return statement has the following component for rendering this column:

```
<Column type={"buttons"}>
    <Button text="View Schedule"
        icon="event"
        hint="View Volunteer Schedule"
        onClick={viewVolunteerSchedule}>
    </Button>
</Column>
```

How do I go about accessing this particular row's "role" variable in a datagrid?, so that I might make this button only visible under certain conditions?

I tried adding the line:

```
visible={data.role==='Volunteer'}
```

but this doesn't seem to be the correct data as it only made them all invisible. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.